# Backup script in Server

Tags: server

I am using Ubuntu  12.10 server edition Now i need script which will backup Samba Share to USB drive attached to the server and also generate the back up log with Log File format containing File Name, Size and Time

Also confirm the Crontab Settings

Thanks in advance

Comment: 12.10 is EOL(End Of Life). please upgrade to a newer version. 16.04 will be release this Thursday, and will be supported for 5 years

Comment: 12.10 is ***super*** dead. Replacing it with a *fresh* install should be your priority for the day. Anything as old as 12.10 connected to the internet, especially running services, is almost certainly infected with something by now. It hasn't had a single security update in 2 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have installed `rsync` install them

```
sudo apt-get install rsync
```

Create script `backup_script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script to backup personal files to the external USB drive.
# Specify the mount point here (DO NOT end mount_point with a forward-slash).
mount_point='/mnt/'

echo "#####"
echo ""
# Check whether target volume is mounted, and mount it if not.
if ! mountpoint -q ${mount_point}/; then
    echo "Mounting the external USB drive."
    echo "Mountpoint is ${mount_point}"
    if ! mount ${mount_point}; then
        echo "An error code was returned by mount command!"
        exit 5
    else echo "Mounted successfully.";
    fi
else echo "${mount_point} is already mounted.";
fi
# Target volume **must** be mounted by this point. If not, die screaming.
if ! mountpoint -q ${mount_point}/; then
    echo "Mounting failed! Cannot run backup without backup volume!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Preparing to transfer differences using rsync."

# Use the year to create a new backup directory each year.
current_year=`date +%Y`
# Now construct the backup path, specifying the mount point followed by the path
# to our backup directory, finishing with the current year.
# (DO NOT end backup_path with a forward-slash.)
backup_path=${mount_point}'/rsync-backup/'${current_year}

echo "Backup storage directory path is ${backup_path}"

echo "Starting backup of /home/XXX/Pictures . . . "
mkdir --parents ${backup_path}/Pictures
# This time use the -a flag with the tee command, so that it appends to the end
# of the rsync-output.txt file rather than start a new file from scratch.
sudo rsync --archive --verbose --human-readable --itemize-changes --progress --no-o --no-g \
--delete --delete-excluded \
/home/XXX/Pictures/ ${backup_path}/Pictures/ 2>&1 | tee -a /home/XXX/rsync-output.txt


echo ""
echo "####"
```

You must change

- mount point of your ext USB - in example I use `/mnt/`
- path to folder you wish to backup - in exampl I use `/home/XXX/Pictures`
- place to to write log file - in example I use `/home/XXX/`

Give script execute privilege

```
chmod +x /path_to_script/backup_script.sh
```

Setup `crontab` to run this command on every `x` period of time

For editing `crontab` run

```
crontab -e
```

For running command on every 5 min code is

```
*/5 * * * * /path_to_script/backup_script.sh
```

on every hour

```
0 */1 * * * /path_to_script/backup_script.sh
```

to run on 4 am

```
0 4 * * * /path_to_script/backup_script.sh
```

Optionaly, you can send log file to your mail with command

```
mail -s "SMB backup" your@mail.com < /path_to_log/rsync-output.txt
```

Setup cron to do for you

```
0 4 * * * mail -s "SMB backup" your@mail.com < /path_to_log/rsync-output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different packages you can use for backups. I personally use `rsnapshot` which encapsulates `rsync`.

There you have some configuration-file where you can specify all your wishes.